# Use of fragment in UI

Tags: android-widget, android

Question: I have to create a tablet application. In this i want to make use of fragments.In one fragment there will be list and in the second fragment there will be grid.
I have gone through the article present at [Android](http://www.android.com/) developers site, but I am not sure for that.
Please guide.

Comment: answer: here is a link on [how to use fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/).

Comment: After exploring various articles i made a view containing two fragments. I need communication between the two fragment. How can i do that??

Comment: that's the basis of using fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i explored various tutorials but i found http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial very helpful.
The implementation is provided step wise with good explanation. It will really help to those who are new to fragments.